# I want to change gps setting programatically in android but having crash

Tags: android

ERROR I'm Getting :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE from pid=15200, uid=10175
```

I am using this code. It's not working for me on any version...

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
 intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
 this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

 String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
 if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
     final Intent poke = new Intent();
     poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
     poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
     poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
 }
public static public void turnGPSOff()
{
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you shown in the your question has been stopped working from Android version 4.4. Your will fire this Exception starting from Kitkat version java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE

For The security purpose Google developer has block above both methods which were previously working fine.
Hence conclusion is that You can not programmatically start GPS On or Off.